Galois group of $x^3+x^2-2x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
Find the Galois group of $p(x)= x^3+x^2-2x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Note that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the rational root test. I'm trying to avoid using Cardano/resolvent/discriminant to do this. Is there any way to break this up nicer that doesn't utilize the resolvent/discriminant?

in $\mathbb F_3[x]$ it factors as $(x-1)(x^2+1)$, so the Galois group contains a transposition and so it must be $S_3$

The discriminant of a cubic is easy and nice, so I don't see why one should avoid it. See the notes by K. Conrad for it here. The discriminant is not a square, so the Galois group is $S_3$, see Theorem $2.1$.

Check the problem, I would expect to see  $x^3+x^2-2x-1$

@WillJagy oh, you're right. Thanks. I'll edit the post. Still irreducible though :(

$x^3+x^2-2x-1$ is a duplicate at this site. See for example this one, and many others. Please check before posting. Now the discriminant is  a square, namely $7^2$, so the Galois group is $A_3$.

@user8268, indeed, invoking a smidge of algebraic number theory is often the best way to actually compute/understand anything in Galois theory! ... but, yeah, though I've occasionally toyed with the idea of introducing the relevant alg no th when teaching Galois theory, I've repeatedly found that it's not actually feasible. Too bad. :)

@paulgarrett This specific result is often stated in Galois theory courses just as a fact, without proof. It's not that complicated, but most students don't have the required knowledge in commutative algebra at this point.

Maybe you could specify that you are interested in the Galois group of the splitting field of the polynomial in question.

In textbooks this polynomial is one of those "famous" for the property: if $r$ is a root, then $r^2-2$ is another. That, in turn is a consequence of the trigonometric identity: If $f(x)=x^2-2$ then $f(2\cos x)=2\cos 2x$. It does yield nice examples of cyclic splitting fields.
